# PowerShell - how to tell if file is WHQL signed or attestation signed

Tags: powershell

**How can I tell if a .cat file is Attestation signed or WHQL signed?**

I know from documentation I can use [Get-AuthenticodeSignature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-authenticodesignature?view=powershell-7.4) to get information about the Authenticode signature for a file. I also know it can be [Attestation signed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/code-signing-reqs#windows-10-attestation-signed-drivers-for-testing-scenarios) or [WHQL signed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/whql-release-signature), but I'm not sure how to tell which it is. I tried asking ChatGPT this question, and after some prompting it responded with this:

*"Look for the Issuer and Subject fields in the certificate information.
WHQL-signed catalog files often have an issuer related to Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher or a similar trusted authority."*

```
# Get information about the catalog file's digital signature
$catalogSignature = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $catalogFilePath

# Check if the catalog signature indicates WHQL or Attestation signing
if ($catalogSignature.Issuer -like "*Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher*") {
    Write-Host "The catalog file is WHQL-signed."
} else {
    Write-Host "The catalog file is Attestation-signed."
}
```

But that only accounts for one possibility, and I understand there are a number of other possible issuers. Is there a better way to tell without having to list out all possible issuers?

Comment: I believe MS issued attestation certificates include the OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.5.1`.  I know nothing about how to extract that information, but it may help you find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been very difficult to find information on this, but from Clifford's comment and from what I'm seeing on this page [IX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certenroll/nn-certenroll-ix509extensionenhancedkeyusage), it seems the only way to tell is from the OID. If the OID is 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.5 or 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.7 then it is WHQL. If it is 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.5.1 then it is attestation.

The property can be accessed by doing this

```
$catalogSignature = Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $catalogFilePath
```

(as mentioned in the question) then on the variable access `.SignerCertificate.Extensions`, which is an array. One of the items in the array should be of type `X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension`, which has `EnhancedKeyUsages`, a collection of OID's. The OID with `FriendlyName` "Windows Hardware Driver Verification" is the target OID.